# DBWeaver in windows cannot connect to postgres server running in WSL 2

Tags: windows, postgresql, wsl-2

Hello I am successfully using postgresql DB in my WSL2 ubuntu and its working fine, but i need to see data in DBWeaver but unfortunately I cannot connect as it shows no connection available, but if I run 127.0.0.1:4000 or anyother port, i can easily see my server running in WSL2 ubuntu , from windows, but cannot connect DBWeaver to WSL2 ubuntu postgresql.
Need your help to connect DBWeaver(in windows) to postgresql or any other DB server running in WSL2 ubuntu
[image]

[image]

But this is the Database present in my WSL2 machine
[image]

[image: Lastly I have added a pic of WSL2 and DBWeaver at the same frame]

> N.B: I alternatively tried to run postgres on windows and use that postgres running on windows to access from WSL2 ubuntu, but they dont work at all , showing there is no psql server running in the specified address and port.

But either way will work for me, any help is very much appreciated

Comment: it says iot_dev does not exist. Change database name to postgres and try to connect

Comment: yes , but you can see that iot dev indeed exists

Comment: Maybe you have multiple database server installed and you are trying to connect wrong one which has no iot_dev